# Questions regarding Parliamentary Procedure

Tags: discussion, questions

Would questions about parliamentary procedure be acceptable here? I'm just necessarily referring to say the US House of Representatives or the US Senate rules of order but Robert's Rules of Order Revised. Most legislatures, and some private organizations, use these documents to govern their body. The description of the site is ask questions about policy so I figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking here, but I'll give it a go.

Questions regarding Parliamentary procedures are in general on-topic, provided that they relate directly to the running of a **political** body or organisation.

Questions related to when those same rules are used outside of and unrelated to the political landscape such as in a private organisation (perhaps to run their AGM or similar) are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue that Roberts Rules of Order is sufficiently prevelant in private organizations as to be on-topic.  Politics exists within corporations as well.

As stated, few legislative bodies use Robert directly, but they are close enough to where it would provide some guidance.